# Default selected value not working in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to set default selected value for my dropdown list. My code looks like this:

```
        <select v-model="newSelectedUnit" @change="selectUnit(newSelectedUnit)" class="custom-select">
          <option v-for="unit in units" :key="unit.id" :value="unit.id" :selected="unit.id == Selectedunit.id">{{ unit.name }}</option>
        </select>
```

but there's no default selected value. I already tried to hardcoded `Selectedunit.id` to `32712` (which is one of the unit's IDs):

```
            <select v-model="newSelectedUnit" @change="selectUnit(newSelectedUnit)" class="custom-select">
              <option  v-for="unit in units" :key="unit.id" :value="unit.id" :selected="unit.id == 32712">{{ unit.name }}</option>
            </select>
```

In Chrome inspector there's an `<option>` tag with value of `32712`:

```
<option value="32712">CYLINDER</option>
```

but it's not selected by default.

**EDIT:**
I noticed that there's a problem with `selected` atribute. In above example, if i set another attribute: :selectedXXX="unit.id == 32712" i've got expected attribute in Chrome dev tools:

```
<option selectedXXX="true" value="32712">CYLINDER</option>
```

**EDIT2:** 
If I remove `v-model="newSelectedUnit"` I've got selected value set correctly! But why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either "`@change` and `:selected`"  or "`v-model`", but not both.

Now the `v-model` on `<select>` will try to select the unit based on the value in `newSelectedUnit`

> If the initial value of your v-model expression does not match any of the options, the  element will render in an “unselected” state.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select

Comment: Yup very clear - thank you! This is a tricky and very important concept to grasp when dealing with selects in Vue.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using materialize css template, it's with a

`select {
    display:none
  }`

add in your default app css

`select: {
    display: block
 }`

it'll appear again!